# You've entered too many arguments for this function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My Excel IF function is throwing a `too manyArguments` error, however if I remove one I get an error that I'm missing a parentheses. If I add one it's too many. If I take one away it's not enough. I can't seem to find the answer.

The following formula gets a missing error:

```
=IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=10),12,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7>15),16,,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=10),12,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<10),14,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<=15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7>15,18),18,))))))
```

The following formula gets too many error:

```
=IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=10),12,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7>15),16,,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=10),12,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<10),14,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<=15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7>15,18),18,)))))))
```

Comment: You probably need to make sure the closing `)`s are all in the right place ... and that there are the same number of `(` and `)`.

Comment: I now get "FALSE" instead of the number:=IF(AND(B8="Loose  Stacked",D7<10),10,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Loose stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<10),12,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<10),14,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<=15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7>15),18)))))))))

Comment: What do expect as a result if B8 is not *"Loose stacked, Barrel Stacked* or *Laced* or D7 is blank? Your current formula has 'holes' that are not accounted for.

Comment: Whenever I see a long formula like this, I think there must be a better way to do it. It might be worth it to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1516634/edit) to provide some sample data and explain what the formula should accomplish

Comment: here is a the spread sheet:https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=0af89169566f2c8b&page=view&resid=AF89169566F2C8B!314&parId=AF89169566F2C8B!127&app=Excel What I am trying to achieve is depending on the Pile Config. selected; "Loose Stacked","Barrel" or "Laced",(cell B10) and the height of the pile(cell D9)The conversion factor(cell J7) should display the appropriate  # of tires /cu.yd. ie. If I select "Loose Stacked"  with a height of less than 10ft.  (10) for 10 Tires/Cubic Yard  is the conversion factor, if 10 to 15 ft.  is inputted it should return (12) for 12 Tires/Cubic Yard and so on.

Comment: the "Loose Stacked" selection is giving me only FALSE in stead of the value here is my formula   =IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=10),10,IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=10),12,IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=15),12,IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9>15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<10),12,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=10),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9>15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<10),14,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<=15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9>15),18)))))))))))   the other two work fine no problems just the Loose stacked part of the formula is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Both formulas contain:

**16,,**

remove one of the commas.

Comment: I saw that and removed it but still get the error.

Comment: I now get "FALSE" instead of the number:=IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<10),10,IF(AND(B8="Loose Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Loose stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<10),12,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7<=15),14,IF(AND(B8="Barrel Stacked",D7>15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<10),14,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7<=15),16,IF(AND(B8="Laced",D7>15),18)))))))))