# IF statment giving "FALSE" instead of numerical value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Instead of the numeric value being returned, Im getting "FALSE" for "Loose Stacked"selection in the cell
all the other selections  "Barrel Stacked" and "Laced" returns the correct value all except  "Loose Stacked". I tried adding "" around 
the value in the formula but sill getting FALSE instead of the value.

IF STATEMENT:

```
=IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=10),10,IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=15),12,IF(AND(B10="Loose Stacked",D9>15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=10),12,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9>15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<10),14,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<=15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9>15),18)))))))))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [You've entered too many arguments for this function](https://superuser.com/questions/1516634/youve-entered-too-many-arguments-for-this-function)

Comment: Are you certain that `Loose Stacked` in `B10` is absolutely the same as the three instances of `Loose Stacked` in your formula?  Your formula seems to work OK here.

Comment: yes they are the same

Comment: It just keeps coming up false instead of the value.

Comment: the others work fine not a problem just the firt part of the formula that starts with 'Loose Stacked"

Comment: "loose Stacked", "Barrel Stacked" and "Laced" are all coming from a drop-down list.

Comment: I can email the worksheet to you for you to see the problem first hand.

Comment: Upload it to a site like **OneDrive** or **Dropbox** and post a link here.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?cid=0af89169566f2c8b&page=view&resid=AF89169566F2C8B!314&parId=AF89169566F2C8B!127&app=Excel

Comment: Thanks for any assistance you can render.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula looks fine, it could be due to too many arguments that exceed the limitation of Excel.  Different versions of the Excel may have different limit and I didn't do the research what's the limitation - but when you reach the limitation it could make your formula unreadable and not easy to maintain or debug.

For your question, you can achieve similar result with `VLOOKUP()` and `MATCH()` as below:
[image: Solution example]

Here, I added a lookup table at `F5:I7`.  For any value greater than 0 (i.e. cell F5), row 5 will be returned; for those starting from 10 (i.e. cell F6), row 6 will be returned, etc.  This is done with `=VLOOKUP(...)` part of the solution.

We need to tell `VLOOKUP` which column to return (i.e. column G/H/I).  It is the 3rd parameter of `VLOOKUP`, and I used `MATCH(B10,$F$4:$I$4,0)` to determine which column to return. The `MATCH()` function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range.

For example, when "Loose Stacked" is searched from `F4:I4`, `2` is returned from `MATCH(B10,$F$4:$I$4,0)` as it is the second item.  The `VLOOKUP(10,F5:I7,MATCH(...))` becomes `VLOOKUP(10,F5:I7,2)` and therefore return `G6` or the value 12.

The good thing to use `VLOOKUP` rather than the nested `IF` is the better readability and maintainability of your formula.  You just need to change the table if you need to change anything in the future.

Comment: Thank you Will give it a whirl...Thanks

Comment: I found another work around ;=IF(OR(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<10),10,IF(OR(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=10),12,IF(OR(B10="Loose Stacked",D9<=15),12,IF(OR(B10="Loose Stacked",D9>15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<10),12,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=10),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9<=15),14,IF(AND(B10="Barrel Stacked",D9>15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<10),14,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9<=15),16,IF(AND(B10="Laced",D9>15),18)))))))))))

Comment: @WayneSeymour Changing the `AND` to `OR` will change the entire logic. Try to input "Loose Stacked" with cell `D9` set to 8, 12 and 16 and see if that's still your desired output?